# CSS fill a parent div using list items in vertical direction

Tags: html, css

I have two columns, in one of them there is a list, I want to fill its parent using this list items. A kind of floating distance between items. How Can I do this?

```css
 * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Create two unequal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
  float: left;
  height: 300px; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */

}


.left {
  width: 20px;
}


.right span{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: normal;
  }
/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.grad-step{
  height:1%;
}
.gradient {
/*    width: 100%; */
/*       height:100%; */
   white-space: nowrap;
   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   top: 0px;
  }
.result-display{
   white-space: nowrap;
  
    height: 100%;

/*    position: relative; */
/*    display: inline-block; */
}
 .result-display ol {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
   counter-reset: commands;
     list-style:  none;
    
    height: 100%;

  }
.right {
  width: 90%;
  padding: 10px;

}
.right ol{
    list-style:  none;
  height: 100%;
}
 .right .domain-min {
   
   left: 0;
   font-size: 11px;
   bottom: 0;
  }

  .right .domain-med {
  
   left: 0;
/*    text-align: center; */
   font-size: 11px;
   top: 50%;
  }

  .right .domain-max {
  
   left: 0;
   font-size: 11px;
   top: 100%;
  }
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column left" style="background-color:#aaa;">
<div class="result-display"><ol><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#ff0000"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#ff0000"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#ff0000"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#ff2d00"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#ff5100"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#ff6b00"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#ff7f00"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#ff9020"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#ff9e3e"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#ffaa57"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#ffb46c"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#ffbe7f"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#ffc690"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#ffce9f"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#ffd4ad"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#ffdbb9"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#ffe0c5"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#ffe6d1"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#ffeadb"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#ffefe6"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#fff3ef"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#fff7f8"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#fff9ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#f7f4ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#f0f0ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#eaedff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#e4eaff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#e0e7ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#dce5ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#d8e3ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#d5e1ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#d2dfff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#cfdeff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#cddcff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#cadbff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#c8d9ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#c6d8ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#c4d7ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#c3d6ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#c1d5ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#bfd4ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#bed3ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#bcd2ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#bbd1ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#bad0ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#b9cfff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#b8cfff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#b6ceff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#b5cdff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#b4cdff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#b4ccff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#b3cbff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#b2cbff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#b1caff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#b0caff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#afc9ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#afc9ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#aec8ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#adc8ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#adc7ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#acc7ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#abc7ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#abc6ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#aac6ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#aac6ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#a9c5ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#a9c5ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#a8c5ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#a8c4ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#a7c4ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#a7c4ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#a6c3ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#a6c3ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#a5c3ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#a5c3ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#a5c2ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#a4c2ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#a4c2ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#a4c2ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#a3c1ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#a3c1ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#a3c1ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#a2c1ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#a2c1ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#a2c0ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#a2c0ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#a1c0ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#a1c0ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#a1c0ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#a1c0ff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#a0bfff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#a0bfff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#a0bfff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#a0bfff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#a0bfff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#9fbfff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#9fbfff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#9fbfff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#9fbeff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#9fbeff"></li><li class="grad-step" style="background-color:#9fbeff"></li></ol></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column right" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <ol>
    <li class="domain-min">0</li><li class="domain-med">0.5</li><li class="domain-max">1</li>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this example I want to put the list in right column similar to this picture.
[image]
In my case there is 3 items, so one of them must be in top, one in middle and one at the end. I want to make it somehow floating, so if I add two more items to my list it should be adjusted. It does not matter if the position of the ticks is not accurate.
thanks

Comment: your question is not so clear, so you want the list to be on the left and the text on the right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use table with rowspan for background cell. this way its always aligned

```css
body{
  background: red;
}

#backgroundCell{
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #0d2062, #003d7d, #005993, #0075a5, #0091b3, #2fa5b8, #53b8bc, #76cbc0, #98d9bf, #bbe6c1, #ddf2c8, #fdfed4);
  padding: 0;
  width: 30px;
}

.custom-table-wrapper{
  background-color: #FCFCFC;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 160px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.custom-table th{
  padding-bottom:20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}


.custom-table .line{
  width: 10px;
  padding: 0;
}

.custom-table td{
  width: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.custom-table .data{
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-table-wrapper">
  <table class="custom-table">
    <tr>
      <th colspan=3>EST. GDP (2010)</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan=8 id="backgroundCell"></td>
      <td class="line"><hr></td>
      <td class="data"> $0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="line"><hr></td>
      <td class="data"> $2,000,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="line"><hr></td>
      <td class="data"> $4,000,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="line"><hr></td>
      <td class="data"> $6,000,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="line"><hr></td>
      <td class="data"> $8,000,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="line"><hr></td>
      <td class="data"> $10,000,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="line"><hr></td>
      <td class="data"> $12,000,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="line"><hr></td>
      <td class="data"> $14,000,000</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```